# Adjust line background in UITextView base on text size

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, uikit, uitextview

I'm having a problem here with this one, I have a `UITextView` that has a Yellow Pad Paper like background. but what I really wanted is to have a DYNAMIC LINES in that background... If I adjust the font size of the text or press ENTER, the YELLOW LINES should also adjust base on how big or small the text is. See screen shot of what I've achieved so far.

[image]

I need to know what framework should I study to achieve this one.

Comment: Add code on how you've added the background. Looking at it, it's probably a background image, which won't work. You will need to draw the lines yourself if you want to change them based on font size.

Comment: play with NSAttributedString.It provides all what you need. Underline,foregroundcolor,background color and much more

Comment: did you try adding underline for the whole text?

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys. Yeah it is still an image... so for now, i think i need to study how to draw and this NSAttributedString. Is there any specific topic that i need to know about drawing this lines in UITextView?

Comment: check this link [NoteView](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/noteview),[TextView Search](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=textview) i thing , this is what you are looking for.

Comment: NoteView is a good starting point. If you just brainlessly want that functionality, then just download and add it to your project. If you want to know how it's done, study the code and spend 4-5 hours trying to recreate it.

Comment: Thanks Pawan. I see how NoteView works and it's perfectly fit to what I want to do... I just see some bug when I hit ENTER multiple times, the line doesn't align anymore. Btw, I just have to edit the code in drawRect: to fix this one, I hope so... So, how can I make Pawan's answer become the answer in this post?